# Parse HTML Page, include all css styles

Tags: c#, html, css, email

I want to send a complete html page as an email and want to include all the css styles into the email. Is there any library that creates me one html page with all the css styles correctly included. (Conside you can import css files which also have to be opened and included.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to send a page without includes? Am I right? How much control do you have over the page building? How complex is it - masterpages, controls etc?

Comment: I have no control over the page building - it is a html page, generated by typo3 with multiple css includes and css imports

Comment: It is worth bearing in mind that CSS support can be patchy with mail clients. E.g. Gmail will not apply any styles that are included in the `head`. It is worth reading this [guide to CSS support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). Unfortunately with emails I tend to resort to coding like it's the 90's - inline styles and table layout.

Comment: Not an anwer because it doesn't include external CSS, and I know this is an old post, but I finally (2 years late!) got this up on github and in nuget: https://github.com/lukeschafer/HtmlCleanser

Answer (score 0):

The closest I came to this was having to send a control without includes, and I built this as a server control, read the css files ( and js files ) and write them out. However for an entire page, you might have more difficulty.

I do not believe that there is anything to do this. If you can read the entire page code, doing find and replaces may be your easiest answer. Find the csss  tag, replace the inner contents with the values from the file in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this: http://martinnormark.com/move-css-inline-premailer-net

Im in the process of testing it myself in order to generate some Word documents with inline styles...i will add the results later...

Update:
It works althought Word 2010 applies some of the inline styles as it likes...didnt try with previous versions of word